# Recompile scss files to change style without having to change them

Tags: css, file, compilation, sass

Searched an answer to this for a while and couldn't find, except: "Just change and save the file again".

Well, i have a lot of css files, and i just want to change the style to compressed without having to open each one of them, change something, save and close.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) can do what you need. I highly encourage you to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

the correct command should be:

sass --force --update scss/:css/ --style compressed

this will "force" all the files to be compiled and with this new style, compressed.